# go off vs get off?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

what's the difference between the following sentences:

> 1 He got off at the wrong bus stop.

> 2 He went off at the wrong bus stop.

Comment: Broadly, the first is about arriving, the second is about departing.

Comment: 1. is correct. 2. is something I've never heard. "Go (or went) off" is usually used to mean doing something explosive, like yelling at someone or doing a bunch backflips in a row, etc. (i.e. going off like a bomb/rocket).

Comment: _Went off_ could also mean _went away, departed_, but it's not appropriate for getting off the bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"He got off of" means he left the bus. "He went off of" is simply not used in any comparable sense.  One could say "He went off on a long rant about politics." which is a metaphorical use implying thaqt he left the path of the conversation. One could also say "He went off on a journey", which simply means "He departed", but "he went off of" is not a standard usage, and I haven't been able to think of a plausible context for it.

The form "he got of at" focuses on the place where the left the bus (or train or other form of transport). The form "he went off at" is only used to me4an "he spoke angrily toward" . For example "He went off at her when she told him his application as invalid."  This is a metaphorical use of "went off" implicitly comparing the person's speech to an explosion, particularly the explosion of a bomb or a gun. Even in this sense it is not a very common usage, in my experience.